# Aizen vs Everyone

Tags: bleach

During the battle: Aizen vs. The Gotei 13 & The Visored (Episode 292, 293 and 294), Aizen was stabbed by [Shinji](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Shinji_Hirako), [Suì-Fēng](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Su%C3%AC-F%C4%93ng),  [Shunsui](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Shunsui_Ky%C5%8Draku) and [Hitsugaya](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/T%C5%8Dshir%C5%8D_Hitsugaya). However, it turned out that [Hinamori](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Momo_Hinamori) was stabbed due to Aizen's ability.

To my understanding, Aizen's ability could affect any of the Shinigami in Soul Society because they all had seen his power before. But Ichigo had not seen it and that was why he was considered to be such an asset. Aizen implied that he had been using his ability since he arrived. I would have thought Ichigo would have seen through the ability from the start.

If Aizen had activated his ability before he arrived, Ichigo should have seen through it. If he activated after Ichigo arrived, how did Gotei 13 not see though it earlier?

My questions: when did Aizen activate his ability and switch with Hinamori and how come it affected Ichigo?

Comment: I thought it happened before ichigo could stop it/understand what was going on. Aizen was constantly using his ability on those who had already seen it but hadn't done what he needed to do to induce it on ichigo a that point. I never understood what that was.

Comment: What makes you think that he used his ability only once in the battle?

Comment: @ytg I assumed he could not activate his ability once it was already activated without deactivating it momentarily

Comment: I imagine the working of his ability more like Getsuga Tenshou and less like Senbonzakura. But we don't have any information about that AFAIK.

Comment: AFAIK it didn't affect Ichigo. It has been forever since I watched this part, but Ichigo didn't take direct part in the confrontation, it just happened so quickly that Ichigo was probably wondering just what their attack strategy actually was. IMO it wouldn't make much sense to instead show the fight from Ichigo's point of view and just explain Aizen's trick every time it happens.

Comment: I don't recall Ichigo ever being exposed to his release.  I'll answer the question proper when I find a more suitable box to.

Answer (score 5):

The requirement for Kyoka Suigetsu's Kanzen Saimin is that Aizen needs to have everyone see it released once, that is going from normal form into its shikai form. After that, whenever Aizen activates it, even if they don't see its release, they will be affected.

Aizen replied to Hirako Shinji, "Since when are you under the impression that I'm not using my power?" This means, from the very beginning, he is using it. It wasn't mentioned since when, but probably ever since he shows up, or during the time he was trapped inside the firewall made by Head Captain Yamamoto Genryuusai Shigekuni. One thing for sure is that he activated it before Ichigo came. That's why, Ichigo wasn't affected by it. Ichigo didn't see the release. What he saw is its released form already.

Ichigo wasn't affected by it. He was just confused with what he saw, that the 3 captains are stabbing Hinamori.

Adding to the when he switched with Hinamori part, we cannot answer that. We too as the viewer are under the effect of Kyoka Suigetsu (as in what was shown to us was from the captains' point of view). Possibly from the very moment Hinamori was down. That was Aizen faking it while the real Hinamori is still fighting.